# MYSQLI Statement error showing incorrect but its correct

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am getting following error from PHP and MYSQL, but the SQL statement is correct, I grabbed it direct from [PHPmyadmin,](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JBegmFRvtNYU5rTFpOUXlnLVk/view?usp=sharing) I have included a picture from PHPMYADMIN showing the table.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM company';

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    (data from result's)
    }
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
   exit();
}
```

Result: (There is nothing from $mysqli->error;)

Error: SELECT * FROM company

Inserted 2 rows into the table, still getting same error.

[2 rows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JBegmFRvtNanlGQXB6aU5qTzA/view?usp=sharing)

Removed the first if statement.

Now getting following error:

( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mkpenterprices\Research.php on line 248

Finally got the SQL to run but its not populating anything on the javascript section.

Comment: This would seem to indicate that there are no rows in the `company` table.  Which is a valid condition that you are treating as an error.

Comment: Yes, there are no rows but its failing on the first if statement, the 2nd if statement does nothing if 0 row's.

Comment: How is it failing on the first `if` statement?  You show the output from the `else` block in the second `if` statement.  This is exactly the output I'd expect if there are zero rows, which you state is correct.  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @David No, John is right. Please take a closer look at the (horribly) formatted code.

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: @JohnWilliams - you're looking to see if the query is returning a literal TRUE in your first if statement; that won't happen with a SELECT statement. Instead, you should be getting a result object, which will never resolve to TRUE

Comment: @arkascha: Ah, I see now.  Formatting is important :)

Comment: Apart from that: you execute the query _twice_. That is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM company';


$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if(!$result){
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
   exit();

}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```